# Flutter: Navigator.push inside listTile is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

Navigator.push is not working()
When I click on it nothing happends, no error, no change page, nothing...

```
ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.pencil),
          title: const Text('Edit Profile'),
          onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => EditProfilePage(
                   uid: userData['uid'])));
                   Navigator.pop(context);
         },
       ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Navigator.pop(context);`

Explantation: You're popping the page immediately after pushing to it that's why it was behaving as if you weren't pushing at all.

Comment: Thanks! I was following a tutorial and they have it so I think it was necesary.

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer.